# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent Node.js and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Node.js and ExpressJS to save a mongoose model. I am getting the error of `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` I think it has to do with the line `res.redirect("/dashboard/it/model");` conflicting with `setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),` from my route, the code in the setRedirect is below labeled. The setRedirect is from a middleware called `middleware-responder` that came as part of the template I am using to create Stripe user accounts. I can not remove it as far as I know. my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/joshk132/asset-management) I have committed all files that are not test files and are relevant (no unneeded views ect than what is already there)

Save Model

```
if(type=="aps"){
      var newAccessPoint = {
          name: name,
          manufacturer: manufacturer,
          model: model,
          range: range, 
          bands: bands,
          channel: channel,
          poe: poe,
          notes: notes,
          signout: signout,
          author:author
        };
      // Create a new access point and save to DB
      AP.create(newAccessPoint, function(err, newlyCreated){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              //redirect back to models page
              res.redirect("/dashboard/it/model");
          }
      });
    }
```

Route

```
app.post('/dashboard/it/model/new',
    setRender('dashboard/it/modelCreate'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    dashboard.getDefault,
   (req, res) => {
```

setRedirect code

```
exports.setRedirect = function(options){
  return function(req, res, next){
   if(req.redirect){
     req.redirect = _.merge(req.redirect, options);
   } else {
     req.redirect = options;
   }
   next();
 };
};
```

setRender code

```
exports.setRender = function(view){
  return function(req, res, next){
    req.render = view;

    next();
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are trying to send a response to the client when you already closed the connection.

Hard to tell by the way you are showing us your code but it seems like you are redirecting to options and then in the same request you are redirecting to dashboard/it/model

Comment: No redirect to option, what you are seeing is the options is the value in `setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),` so the redirect there is 'login' but that is only if the user is not logged in. I tried commenting out that line and got a new error. `Path must be a string. Received undefined`

Comment: If the user is already logged in then you just call next() and move into the next middleware, then at the end of the request, when you are finished doing what you had to do, you do the redirect. You only need to redirect when there is no user logged in, no need to redirect if there is an user, you just continue with the request

Comment: Okay so commenting out that line gives me the error `Path must be a string. Received undefined` so different error than in OP. How do I debug/ solve that error then.

Comment: I have never used middleware-responder before but it says it only attach a redirect to the request object. You could remove the code from setRedirect and only use redirect from the isAuthenticated middleware or after you are done doing whatever you had to do.

Or just remove the setRedirect middleware and redirect directly from isAuthenticated to /login if not authenticated

Comment: I got it to work by removing the last redirect. I could not remove the first one and have it work but removing the last one fixed it. I just kept commenting and uncommenting code till it worked not much logic to that sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I pull your code from github.
I think the error message was clear. in your `getDefault()` middleware you are rendering a response so the server start sending data to your client and just after you try to redirect him to another url. Thats why when your comment out that middleware all work nicely.

Comment: I got it to go away by removing the second render. It still saves and all is good. I haven't posted an answer yet because I was hoping someone would tell me a solution that would fix some of my other errors that are related.